# Are two separate websites useful when discussing mobile and desktop

Tags: website-design, mobile

I am doing an ecommerce web design that will be using a lot of images of realistic items than cant be created in CSS.  One big goal I would like to do is have this site accessible through mobile devices. I do know it would be hard to display the site using all the images so I wanted to know which would be best.

1. Completely code everything in CSS to render a simplistic site excluding all the detailed images.
2. Code a device detection and transfer all requests to another site, subdomain, with no images used.

Comment: This isn't really a graphic design question as much as it is user experience. Perhaps ask there. Regardless, both may be options, but we'd need a bit more info...namely how important these images are to the user experience in general.

Comment: Depending upon usage, media queries in the CSS can be a great deal of help.

Comment: Does this mean that the mobile website will need to have all the functions and features of the desktop? In which case, you need to work out the baseline for things to work properly in the mobile site (since the desktop will be more flexible), and then decide in terms of effort, cost and maintenance which one is better in the long and short term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combined option: Code a device detection and switch to a mobile-html and a mobile-css to render a simplistic site, with less images at a much smaller scale. Webs without images are boring, even on mobile devices.

That would be two separate web sites on the same URL, which is probably what you want.